# spring request parameters binding error

Tags: javascript, java, spring

```
@RequestMapping("/query")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Content> getByQuery(HttpServletRequest request, ContentQuery query) {
    // Handle request.
}
```

This code is going to function as an http wrapper of the ContentQuery object so that i can query content with http-requests from javascript. The automatic binding in Spring binds request parameters to the ContentQuery object.

The problem is that if someone puts an unknown parameter key in the request, the ContentQuery object is stil instantiated, and i don't know how to check if i get unexpected params.

Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: What exactly are you getting in the Content Query in both the scenarios

Comment: The ContentQuery object is instantiated with all fields as their default values. Objects == null, ints = 0, and so on.

If i pass this ContentQuery object to my service i get a list of all content-objects in the system.

Comment: I would like to answer with a 400-Bad Request if there are parameters that does not fit with the ContentQuery object, and likewise if the client does not provide any parameters at all.

Comment: You can put validations in the model or bean "ContentQuery" . and if the the data will not be according validations. It will automatically throw a 400 Bad Request

Comment: I was hoping to avoid editing the ContentQuery bean, but that may be the only way to do this.
It's quite a big CMS, and i'm working on a plugin for it at work. So my hope was that i didn't have to touch the core module (that ContentQuery is a part of)

Comment: then write your own validator and run it in your controller - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html . Then you can return ResponseEntity with any status you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> then write your own validator and run it in your controller - docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/… . Then you can return ResponseEntity with any status you want –  freakman

Thank you for the hint. Haven't used the Validator interface before, but it looks like a clean solution.

Controller:

```
@Autowired
private ContentQueryValidator validator;

@RequestMapping("/query")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<List<Content>> getByQuery(
        HttpServletRequest request, ContentQuery query, BindingResult result) {
    validator.validate(query, result);
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    // No errors. Fetch content from service using query object.
}
```

And the validator:

```
@Component
public class ContentQueryValidator implements Validator{
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return ContentQuery.class.equals(aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
        ContentQuery query = (ContentQuery) obj;

        List<Integer> contentTemplate = query.getContentTemplate();
        List<Integer> displayTemplate = query.getDisplayTemplate();

        if(contentTemplate == null && displayTemplate == null){
            errors.reject("No query provided");
        }
        // More validation here..
    }
}
```